# Quickest way to apply SPARSE on huge existing tables

Tags: sql-server, sparse-column

I have a bunch (> 40) of columns in a huge table (> 27 m records) which I am attempting to set as SPARSE. Each column takes up to 40 minutes to be altered. Is there a way to do this more quickly? Is there some metadata I can modify to quickly set these columns as SPARSE and rebuild the table?

Comment: have you tried `ALTER TABLE schema.yourTableName ALTER COLUMN columnName  datatype SPARSE NULL` ?

Comment: You can always create a new table, load it, and then switch them through renaming.

Comment: @Kin Shah : Unless I am missing something, isn't that the way to set columns as SPARSE? If so, I am just trying to try and do that more quickly.

Comment: did you define with NULL as it will be fast -? @sciron

Comment: @David : Thanks. We are considering that, along with doing this on a DB level (for the table has too many dependencies and dependent tables), and might have to resort to that.

Comment: @Kin, no. I will try that out. I am just wondering if this is different from setting the column as NULLABLE.